# Override a FOSUserBundle RegistrationController

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In FOSUserBundle, i need to override FOSUserBundle RegistrationController because i need to add this:

```
if($user->getType()=="Student") {
    $user->addRole("ROLE_Student");
}
else {
    $user->addRole("ROLE_TEACHER");
}
```

It works when i add it in `vendor--->...---->registrationcontroller`. That's why i need to override registration controller, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not override the controller. You should use the event system! Create an event handler which subscribe to `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETE` and then perform the role addition.

**Documentation:**

- [Symfony: `EventDispatcher` component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/index.html)
- [Symfony: Using events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)
- [FOSUserBundle: Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)

**The listener:**

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(/* ... */)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETE => 'addRole',
        );
    }

    public function addRole(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        // Add the role here
        // ...
    }
}
```

**The service definition:**

```
<service id="my_app.event.registration" class="MyApp\Event\RegistrationListener">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
    <!-- ... -->
</service>
```

Comment: the service is service.yml can you tell how i can do it .                And i don't what can i make code in this functionthe fuction public function __construct(/* ... */)
    {
        // ...
    }

Comment: @razzek You should read the doc: [Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)